# Delphi FMX - Is there a way to get the X, Y co-ordinates of a form in Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I am trying to port an application from VCL to Firemonkey (using Delphi 10.1 Berlin). One of the things that my VCL application does is store the main form's position (x, y) and size (height, width) in an INI file when closed and restore the form to those values when opened again.

In FireMonkey, I am able to get the form's Height and Width, but can't find the X, Y position. Does anyone know how to get these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Form's [`Left`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.Left) and [`Top`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.Top) properties (same as you do in VCL).

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau - I knew I was missing something obvious. (Feel like a bit of an idiot now :) )